# How to fix this css property for header alignment in react app?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am facing some issue with alignment of a header. The header CSS property gets inherited from the app css. e.g in below image, Our mission is a header which i want it to be left aligned. Can someone help here. The app.js and app.css is available in this code snadbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-hooks-527rx9?file=/src/App.js

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-hooks-527rx9?file=/src/App.js

app.js:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div id="app">
      <img id="home-background-image" />
      <div id="project-header">
        <p id="project-exp">Test Site Name</p>
      </div>

      <div id="project-mission-header">
        <h2>Our Mission</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

styles.css

```
#app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#home-background-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background: url("https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fh260/background/20201026/pngtree-futuristic-shape-abstract-background-chemistry-technology-concept-for-website-image_438818.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#project-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  color: white;
}
#project-exp {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
}

#project-mission-header {
  width: 810px;
  justify-content: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to update the width to 100%

```
#project-mission-header {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: left;
}
```

Comment: happy to hear your issue is fixed. I have made a proper answer so that you can mark it as an accepted answer